# Elastic Runtime installation fails with (undefined method `address' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to install PCF (Pivotal Cloud Foundry) on GCP (Google Cloud Platform) as part of a POC.

I have been following the instruction on the [docs](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-11/customizing/gcp.html). Unfortunately, I've hit a road block where my installation of Elastic Runtime fails with following error.

```
Director task 224  Started preparing deployment > Preparing deployment. Done (00:00:02)

Error 100: Unable to render instance groups for deployment. Errors are: 
- Unable to render jobs for instance group 'uaa'. Errors are: 
  - Unable to render templates for job 'uaa'. Errors are: 
    - Error filling in template 'uaa.yml.erb' (line 77: undefined method `address' for nil:NilClass) 
- Unable to render jobs for instance group 'cloud_controller'. Errors are: 
  - Unable to render templates for job 'cloud_controller_ng'. Errors are: 
    - Error filling in template 'cloud_controller_api.yml.erb' (line 204: undefined method `address' for nil:NilClass) 
- Unable to render jobs for instance group 'clock_global'. Errors are: 
  - Unable to render templates for job 'cloud_controller_clock'. Errors are: 
    - Error filling in template 'cloud_controller_clock.yml.erb' (line 178: undefined method `address' for nil:NilClass) 
- Unable to render jobs for instance group 'cloud_controller_worker'. Errors are: 
  - Unable to render templates for job 'cloud_controller_worker'. Errors are: 
    - Error filling in template 'cloud_controller_worker.yml.erb' (line 171: undefined method `address' for nil:NilClass)

Task 224 error

For a more detailed error report, run: bosh task 224 --debug 
===== 2017-08-07 18:22:09 UTC Finished "bundle exec bosh -n deploy"; Duration: 86s; Exit Status: 1
```

**Elastic Runtime Version: `1.11.6-build.4`**

I've tried running this task in the debug mode and from what I can tell, it looks like `syslog_forwarder` is the culprit. Here is the stack trace:

```
D, [2017-08-07 18:21:22 #31053] [task:224] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: Extracting job syslog_forwarder 
D, [2017-08-07 18:21:22 #31053] [task:224] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `address' for nil:NilClass> 
D, [2017-08-07 18:21:22 #31053] [task:224] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: Error filling in template 'uaa.yml.erb' (line 77: undefined method `address' for nil:NilClass) 
uaa/uaa.yml.erb:77:in `block (2 levels) in get_binding' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-template-0.0.0/lib/bosh/template/evaluation_context.rb:135:in `if_link' 
uaa/uaa.yml.erb:76:in `block in get_binding' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-template-0.0.0/lib/bosh/template/evaluation_context.rb:175:in `else' 
uaa/uaa.yml.erb:75:in `get_binding' 
/var/vcap/packages/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `eval' 
/var/vcap/packages/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `result' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-core-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/core/templates/source_erb.rb:20:in `block in render' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-core-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/core/templates/source_erb.rb:19:in `synchronize' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-core-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/core/templates/source_erb.rb:19:in `render' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-core-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/core/templates/job_template_renderer.rb:37:in `block in render' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-core-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/core/templates/job_template_renderer.rb:33:in `map'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-core-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/core/templates/job_template_renderer.rb:33:in `render'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-core-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/core/templates/job_instance_renderer.rb:21:in `block in render' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-core-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/core/templates/job_instance_renderer.rb:17:in `map'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-core-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/core/templates/job_instance_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/job_renderer.rb:40:in `render_job_instance' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/job_renderer.rb:20:in `block in render_job_instances' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/job_renderer.rb:20:in `each' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/job_renderer.rb:20:in `render_job_instances' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/jobs/update_deployment.rb:225:in `block in render_instance_groups_templates' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/jobs/update_deployment.rb:223:in `each' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/jobs/update_deployment.rb:223:in `render_instance_groups_templates' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/jobs/update_deployment.rb:211:in `render_templates_and_snapshot_errand_variables' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/jobs/update_deployment.rb:94:in `block in perform'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/lock_helper.rb:13:in `block in with_deployment_lock' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/lock.rb:79:in `lock' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/lock_helper.rb:13:in `with_deployment_lock' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/jobs/update_deployment.rb:59:in `perform' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/job_runner.rb:106:in `perform_job' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/job_runner.rb:30:in `block in run' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh_common-0.0.0/lib/common/thread_formatter.rb:49:in `with_thread_name' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/job_runner.rb:30:in `run' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/jobs/base_job.rb:10:in `perform' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/jobs/db_job.rb:32:in `block in perform' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bosh-director-0.0.0/lib/bosh/director/jobs/db_job.rb:80:in `block (3 levels) in run' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.4/lib/eventmachine.rb:1046:in `block in spawn_threadpool' 
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.3.0/gems/logging-1.8.2/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:323:in `block in create_with_logging_context'
```

The same stack repeats for `cloud_controller_api.yml.erb`, `cloud_controller_clock.yml.erb`, and `cloud_controller_worker.yml.erb`

I have scoured the internet, but, can't find any useful information and since, we don't yet have any support contract with Pivotal, their engineers won't be able to help.

I would really appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.

I'm downloading `1.11.7-build.5` as I post this and will provide an update after trying that.

**UPDATE:** Exactly the same results with `1.11.7-build.5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the older version (`1.10.21` to be precise) provides better error message.

It turns out that this error occurs when you select `Internal Databases - MySQL and Postgres` option within `Pivotal Elastic Runtime -> Settings -> Databases`.

I changed my selection to `Internal Databases - MySQL` and it fixed the error.